# npm audit fix --force

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install

I wanted to get rid of my vurnerabilities and used

```
npm audit fix --force
```

But i canceled it after a few lines, because it said: "I hope you know what you are doing"

Now if i try

```
npm install
```

i get

```
$ npm install
npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.900.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 < 3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@9.0.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 < 3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@9.0.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 <3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.1.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@8.1.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@9.0.7 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.6 < 3.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-jest@24.0.2 requires a peer of jest@>=24 <25 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 1219421 packages in 12.454s

39 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 23 vulnerabilities (21 low, 2 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

If I install @angular/compiler@8.1.3 i need @angular/compiler@9.0.7 and vise versa

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem i resolved it by running the command "ng update", this command will provide you with packages need to be updated and the commands to update it.Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think question Is about NPM. Not about NG. It can has different Versions of WebPack and Angular.